# XSLT Output Layout

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having hard time generating the desired structure. I have written code that generated structure similar to desired output. But its not the same. Can you please help. I have been stuck on this issue for past 2 days.

I want data from EmployeeO to be displayed in table format in single EmployeeO node.

input.xml

```
<XEmployeeF></XEmployeeF>
<EmployeeO>
<Name>A</Name>
<Age>24</Age>
</EmployeeO>
<EmployeeO>
<Name>B</Name>
<Age>25</Age>
</EmployeeO>
<XEmployeeG></XEmployeeG>
```

Output.xml

```
XEmployeeF
================ EmployeeO
Name  Age  
A 24 
================ EmployeeO
Name  Age  
B 25 
XEmployeeG
```

Desired Output

```
XEmployeeF
================ EmployeeO
Name    Age  
A       24 
B       25 
XEmployeeG
```

Transform.xsl

```
<xsl:template match="/*">

    <xsl:for-each select="*">

    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="starts-with(name(),'X')">
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
     <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="name() = 'EmployeeO'">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('================ ',name())" />
     <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
     <xsl:for-each select="*"> 
     <table>
     <tr>
     <th><xsl:value-of select="concat( name(),'&#160;')" />
         <xsl:text> </xsl:text></th>
     </tr>
     </table>
            </xsl:for-each>
           <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <table><tr><td>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'&#160;')"/></td></tr></table>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>



        </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Please help.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and where you have `Output.xml` and `Desired Output` show the _actual_ output as HTML, not as rendered by the browser.

Comment: The output, I have copied from the eclipse output screen Jim.

Comment: Sorry, but your XSL is outputting HTML, and what you are showing appears to be copy/pasted from something rendered in a browser.  We need to see the actual HTML.

Comment: Will this work for you? http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, you want to generate **plain text**, not any XML, so HTML markup
in the output is not necessary.

One of possible solutions to generate your output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="XEmployeeF"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="EmployeeO[1]" mode="Head"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="EmployeeO"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="XEmployeeG"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), '&#10;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EmployeeO" mode="Head">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('================ ', name(), '&#10;')"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(name(), '        '), 1, 8)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EmployeeO">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(., '        '), 1, 8)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The script above contains 4 templates:

1. `match="/*"` - processing the main element.
2. `match="*"` - processing each element, except those served by "more
   specific" templates. Actually, it is intended for `XEmployeeF` and
   `XEmployeeG`.
3. `match="EmployeeO" mode="Head"` - generating a "title" to be output above
   all `EmployeeO` elements.
4. `match="EmployeeO"` - serving each `EmployeeO` element.

And a remark concerning your XML input: To be properly formed, your content
must be enclosed with a **single** main element, in this case, with any name.